# Google AMP Cache and HTTP/2 – Content delivery via HTTP/2 on mobile devices?

Tags: amp-html, http2, content-delivery-network

The Google AMP Cache serves files up to 12 MB in size via HTTP/2 by default. Even though AMP is not bound to the use on mobile devices, they are the main motivation behind AMP.

I've just read [a paper about the performance of HTTP/2 on cellular networks](https://www.akamai.com/kr/ko/multimedia/documents/technical-publication/http2-performance-in-cellular-networks.pdf).
While they found that HTTP/2 is faster than HTTP/1.1 for small files (2 MB), they also saw that package loss for files that are 8 MB or larger has a higher impact on HTTP/2 than HTTP/1.1, resulting in higher page load times (i.e. HTTP/1.1 is faster than HTTP/2 in this case). In their research 32% of all mobile connections experienced package loss.

Therefore I've been wondering if HTTP/2 really is the way to go for the (Google) AMP Cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP/2 has consistency been shown to be faster for **most** sites. Are there certain scenarios where its is worse - absolutely! - but should you hold back improving *most sites* for the *minority*? No in my opinion.

However, even with that, I think there are other factors you also need to take into account:

AMP pages are designed to be more performance and I would say that, especially for them, 8mb pages should be the exception not the norm. So while it may be more efficient to use HTTP/1.1 for larger pages in certain scenarios - it **is** more efficient for most smaller pages to use HTTP/2.

Should you fall back to HTTP/1.1 for larger pages? Perhaps, but that is more complicated as the protocol is negotiated first before you know the page and downgrading would necessitate a redirect or similar and definitely slow the page down.

Should AMP and the AMP caches restrict to 8Mb rather than 12Mb given they use HTTP/2 and this paper suggests that might be a better limit? Perhaps - but then again it's not like they won't work on HTTP/2, they will fall back gracefully but may not load as fast as if they were on HTTP/1.1.

Also most of the AMP pages themselves should be small, and progressively load non-essential assets (e.g. images or videos). So a large file (which is likely to be an image or a video) may not block the critical rendering of an AMP page anyway even if there is packet loss.

Are all mobile pages loaded over mobile networks? Do any people use mobiles over WiFi networks were package loss should be less (I know I do!). The paper is unclear whether the 32% figure is cellular connections (i.e. not over WiFi) or all mobile connections (i.e. cellular and WiFi)

Google also is experimenting with QUIC underlying HTTP/2 rather than TCP - which addresses the main reason for slowness over the single HTTP/2 connection (that is that a single TCP packet loss will hold up all HTTP/2 streams, and not just the stream that packet belongs too). Granted this only works in Chrome right now so other browser will not benefit from it yet, but again Chrome has a sizable user base.

So based on all that, I think HTTP/2 is definitely the way to go - and especially for AMP pages. As I said in the beginning it's not perfect, and there are some pages which might be slower over it in certain conditions, but the vast majority of pages should be faster over it and therefore it should be used.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. :)

Answer (score 2):

HTTP/2 main purpose is performance, first, why not HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 introduced an official IETF standard; Unfortunately, implementation simplicity also came at a cost of application performance:

- HTTP/1.x clients need to use multiple connections to achieve concurrency and reduce latency;
- HTTP/1.x does not compress request and response headers, causing unnecessary network traffic;
- HTTP/1.x does not allow effective resource prioritization, resulting in poor use of the underlying TCP connection; and so on.

These limitations were not fatal, but as the web applications continued to grow in their scope, complexity, and importance in our everyday lives, they imposed a growing burden on both the developers and users of the web, which is the exact gap that HTTP/2 was designed to address:

**Source:** https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/http2/

And now, quoting a research about Packet loss on HTTP/2 that I read while we started implementing AMP:

> Packet Loss, High-RTT Links, and HTTP/2 Performance
>   Wait, I hear you say, we listed the benefits of using one TCP connection per origin but aren’t there some potential downsides? Yes, there are.
>
> We have eliminated head-of-line blocking from HTTP, but there is still head-of-line blocking at the TCP level (see Head-of-Line Blocking).
>
> Effects of bandwidth-delay product may limit connection throughput if TCP window scaling is disabled.
>
> When packet loss occurs, the TCP congestion window size is reduced (see Congestion Avoidance), which reduces the maximum throughput of the entire connection.
>
> Each of the items in this list may adversely affect both the throughput and latency performance of an HTTP/2 connection. However, despite these limitations, the move to multiple connections would result in its own performance tradeoffs:
>
> Less effective header compression due to distinct compression contexts
>
> Less effective request prioritization due to distinct TCP streams
>
> Less effective utilization of each TCP stream and higher likelihood of congestion due to more competing flows
>
> Increased resource overhead due to more TCP flows
>
> The above pros and cons are not an exhaustive list, and it is always possible to construct specific scenarios where either one or more connections may prove to be beneficial. However, the experimental evidence of deploying HTTP/2 in the wild showed that a single connection is the preferred deployment strategy:
>
> In tests so far, the negative effects of head-of-line blocking (especially in the presence of packet loss) is outweighed by the benefits of compression and prioritization.
>
> Hypertext Transfer Protocol version 2, Draft 2
>
> As with all performance optimization processes, the moment you remove one performance bottleneck, you unlock the next one. In the case of HTTP/2, TCP may be it. Which is why, once again, a well-tuned TCP stack on the server is such a critical optimization criteria for HTTP/2.
>
> There is ongoing research to address these concerns and to improve TCP performance in general: TCP Fast Open, Proportional Rate Reduction, increased initial congestion window, and more. Having said that, it is important to acknowledge that HTTP/2, like its predecessors, does not mandate the use of TCP. Other transports, such as UDP, are not outside the realm of possibility as we look into the future.

**Source:** https://hpbn.co/http2/

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview#cache-optimizations-and-modifications), the Google AMP Cache performs optimizations and modifications and it serves over a secure channel (HTTPS) and uses the latest web protocols (SPDY, **HTTP/2**). Also from this [blog](https://community.akamai.com/community/web-performance/blog/2017/11/09/3-reasons-why-amp-and-cdn-can-work-together), the Google AMP Cache is a proxy-based content delivery network for delivering all valid AMP documents. It fetches AMP HTML pages, caches them, and improves page performance automatically. **When using the Google AMP Cache, the document, all JS files and all images load from the same origin that is using HTTP 2.0 for maximum efficiency.**

Comment: Yeah. My point is – according to the paper I linked above – wouldn't it be more efficient to use HTTP/1.1 instead of HTTP/2, as package loss on mobile devices is quite common and HTTP/1.1 deals with that better on websites, even since the Google AMP Cache allows caching up to 12 MB?